# Packing a static AngularJS website with any web server (e.g. nginx) into a single rpm package

Tags: angularjs, nginx, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

And thank you very much to everyone who responded :)

> I have no experience building rpm packages with such requirements

For several days now, I can’t defeat the task of **packing a static website (AngularJS) by a web server in one rpm package**. That it would be possible to install and receive a ready site on any rhel/centos server.

What did I do.

- Install all needed tools for creating rpmbuild and create non-root
  user for this action
- rpmdev-setuptree && rpm -Uvh
  http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/SRPMS/nginx-1.16.1-1.el7.ngx.src.rpm
- copy my website folder to SOURCE
- edit rpmbuild/SPECS/nginx.spec
- add Source14: website
- add to section %install, after

```
%{__mkdir} -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/nginx
%{__mv} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_sysconfdir}/nginx/html $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/nginx/
```

I tried use

```
cp -r -f %{SOURCE14}/*.* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/nginx/html/
```

and

```
%{__install} -D -pm 755 %{SOURCE14}/*.* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/nginx/html/
```

But after `rpmbuild -bb nginx.spec` I didn`t have any changes in **rpmbuild/BUILD/nginx-1.16.1/html/** folder, it contains only index.html and 50x.html

> Pls help me with resolve this task.
>   Where in the spec file I need add my website copy step?
>   What the best way to modify Nginx default.conf? Because I need to add support AngularJS (add servername, HTTP to https rewrite allow some type of fonts and etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should create a tarball from your website folder. Here is relevant documentation https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/#preparing-source-code-for-packaging
2. Then you need to alter `%prep` section. Which will be tricky if you want to keep the Source0 of original nginx. The documentation is here: https://rikers.org/rpmbook/node70.html#SECTION03541000000000000000 See section "*Using %setup in a Multi-source Spec File*"

Instead of modifying existing nginx spec file, I would suggest you to create new spec file from scratch. Read through existing documentation like:

- https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io/
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-rpm-packages/index.html
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html-single/RPM_Guide/index.html

Back to the core of your issue.

When you do:

```
Source14: website
```

then rpmbuild will include only the directory - or should, I actually never tried it, every case and source code assume only one filename there. The wildcards do not work there. Therefore later `cp -r -f %{SOURCE14}/*.*` does not match anything, because it expands to `cp -r -f website/*.*` but the folder is actually empty.

If you try to do:

```
Source14: website/foo
Source15: website/bar/foo
```

then it will 1) be hell of manual work 2) not work, because SourceX takes only the basename and expect it to be present in rpmbuild/SOURCES/ - and obviously you will have collision sooner or later. Therefore you want to tarball your work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Having dealt with the problem, I solved it.